# Django Model Design (Big model vs multiple)

Tags: sql, django, database-design, django-models

I have a question about designing my models. Suppose I have a following model:

```
class Comment(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='child_comments')
```

Now I would like models for multiple topics (ShoppingList, Games,...). I came to two possible solutions and need help with deciding more suitable one.

1) Make Comment abstract and extend it for every new model wanted.

```
class ShoppingListComment(Comment):
    shopping_list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, related_name='shopping_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I could then query this game comments with something like:

`ShoppingListComment.objects.all()`

2) Add extra nullable Foreing keys directly to comment:

```
class BigCommentModel(models.Model):
    who = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, related_name='child_comments')
    shopping_list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, related_name='shopping_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True),
    game = models.ForeignKey(Game, related_name='game_comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I could then query this game comments with something lile:

```
BigCommentModel.objects.filter(game__isnull=False)
```

Comment: why not keep Comment as ForeignKey to other models like shoppinglistcomment?

Comment: That would be another option. Wouldn't that require 2 joins for every query though? It would become ManyToMany relationship where it isn't neded. One comment can be only on one shopping_list. I also want some clarifications why one way would be better than other (optimizations, maintanance,... )

Comment: foreignkeys don't need joins to resolve a query. If you see a Foreignkey in a database it stores the pk of the entry as a reference and this pk is used for getting data from other table. So if Comment is a foreignkey is ShoppingComment then ShoppingComment table will store a pk of the entry of comment table then it can be retrieved in nearly O(1) time